# vue axios, how to access response headers

Tags: vue.js

Why can't I access the response headers below? They should be accessible on the response object, which I am unpacking into the `data` and `headers` variables. I am thinking it might be trying to access the headers on the Promise, instead of the resolved response object.

```
getDomains({ commit, state }) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const { data, headers } = await axios.get(`http://wordpress.api/wp-json/sslchkr/v1/author/${state.user.id}/domain`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${state.user.token}`
                }
            })
            commit('SET_DOMAINS', data, headers)
            resolve(data)
        } catch(e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this riddle by passing in the response object to SET_DOMAINS, it only takes one argument.

```
SET_DOMAINS(state, res) {
    state.domains.domains = res.data
    state.domains.totalDomains = res.headers['x-wp-total']
    state.domains.totalPages = res.headers['x-wp-totalpages']
}
```